# How to match an intent without data with an intentFilter with dataSchemes?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When you add a data scheme to an intent filter in Android, an intent will match only if it shares the same scheme. If you don't specify any scheme, an intent will match only if it has no data. Now, if my intent filter has a scheme, how can I make it match with an intent that has no data ?

In my case, I want to detect when the wallpaper changes with ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED (I know it is deprecated but I have no other way and it still works). My intent filter has one data scheme ("package", because I also listen for package changes) and since ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED has no data in it, it doesn't match with my intent filter. I could remove the scheme to catch the wallpaper change but then I could not listen for package changes. How can I listen for both package changes with my data scheme and listen for wallpaper change ?

Here is my code to register my custom broadcast receiver (actionReceiver):

```
actionReceiver = new ActionReceiver();
IntentFilter actionFilter = new IntentFilter();
actionFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
actionFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
actionFilter.addDataScheme("package");
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, actionReceiver, actionFilter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many `Intent` filters as you want. Just add another `Intent` filter. Example (in code):

```
IntentFilter filter1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED);
IntentFilter filter2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
filter2.setDataScheme(...)

BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter1);
context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter2);
```

Comment: But then I need to make another broadcast receiver right ?

Comment: No. Are you registering your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest? Or are you doing this dynamically in code?

Comment: I am doing it in the code. Now I've simply created another receiver (even though I didn't want to in the first place because I wanted to keep things simple) and everything works fine. If you have any idea on how I could merge my two receivers into one I am all ears

Comment: You don't need that. Please edit your question and post the code you used to register the receiver (with `Intent` filter) and I will show you how to do it.